# How to implement a write method that return a state

Tags: scala

I have this very frequent type of code :

```
def writeOne(s: S, a: A) : S = …
def writeAll(init: S, l: List[A]) = l.foldLeft(init)(writeOne)
def process = {
  val as : List[A] = …
  val init : S = new S()
  writeAll(init, as)
}
```

Is there a better way, in term of code design, to write that ?

Comment: Better in what terms? Readability? Performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you willing to use [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)? The state monad can help you encapsulate some of the business of threading the state through these operations:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def writeOne(a: A): State[S, Unit] = State.modify(
  s => ??? // Do something with `s` and `a`, returning the new `S`.
)

def writeAll(l: List[A]): State[S, Unit] = l.traverseS_(writeOne)

def process = {
  val as: List[A] = ???
  val init = new S()

  writeAll(as).run(init)
}
```

I don't find your code particularly verbose or hard to read, but if you do feel like you're writing too many methods that take some argument `s: S` and return a new `S`, the state monad is one way to clean things up a bit.

Comment: I have a compilation error on run : found : (S, Unit) required : S

Comment: Have you specified the return type for `process`? If so you can use `writeAll(as).exec(init)` to get only the final state value.